# Grails + Quartz: Threads don't stop properly

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 with Quartz plugin 0.4.2.

Stopping my servers (grails built-in or on Tomcat 6) show me severe warnings that the worker threads couldn't be stopped.

I found many discussions about Spring+Quartz and some configuration examples.
But I didn't found anything with this topic for grails + plugin.

I tried to use the quartz.properties and some settings, but it seems the plugin doesn't use the properties-file.

Does anybody has a hint for using Quartz properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The properties file works for quartz. I added a org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1 and now I've only one worker thread instead of 5. But I've still these SEVERE warnings.

Answer (score 2):

In a Grails app, you configure Quartz using a file `grails-app/conf/QuartzConfig.groovy`, e.g. my Quartz config file contains the following settings:

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = false
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
}
```

Comment: You're right. I also use a QuartzConfig.groovy class for the plugin. But there IMHO you can only set these three settings.
The plugin doku says: "You could also create grails-app/conf/quartz.properties file and provide different options to the Quartz scheduler (see Quartz configuration reference for details)."